# How to decrypt an encrypted String in java

Tags: java, encryption

I have `String s="abc";`
the encryption string is showing : `ðá£ÅÉûË¿~?‰+×µÚ`
and decrypted the same value.

But now I have the same encryption string as `ðá£ÅÉûË¿~?‰+×µÚ`, can I get/ decrypt it bace? below code i am using.

```
String key = "Bar12345Bar12345"; // 128 bit key
// Create key and cipher
Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
// encrypt the text
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
String e=new String(encrypted);
byte[] encrypted1 = cipher.doFinal(e.getBytes());
System.out.println(encrypted.length+" "+encrypted1.length);
System.out.println(e);
// decrypt the text
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
String decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
System.out.println(decrypted);
```

Comment: Your first mistake here is using `String` as a container for binary data. It isn't. You should hold the ciphertext in a `byte[]`.

Comment: why you have encrypted twice the text ? once encrypt is good

Comment: [It works for me](http://ideone.com/9FFpnC). You really don't need the double encryption, since you're not using the second stage encryption result. Also, a string cannot hold binary data as-is. You would need to encode the ciphertext `byte[]` to Hex or Base64 to make it printable.

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. It most likely results in `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"`, but it doesn't have to be. If it changes, you'll lose compatibility between different JVMs.

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: @ArtjomB. It works for you because the code in the question does not match the text. The code decrypts the byte array `encrypted` and in the text, the question is how to decrypt the string "ðá£ÅÉûË¿~?‰+×µÚ". Before someone tries it out: The string is at this stage already corrupted and cannot be decrypted. EJP has in his comment explained why.

Comment: @Mena Your comment does not make much sense. What is 'your encoding' for AES-encrypted binary data?

Comment: @jarnbjo oh. I just read the question halfway through - didn't realize we were talking binary data here. Thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not try to create a string from a random stream of bytes.

If you need a string representation of encrypted text - use some binary safe encoding, like java.util.Base64.

So without fixing the crypto part of your text (as commented by others), what you have to do is:

1. To encode:

   ```
   String text = "abc";
   String key = "Bar12345Bar12345";
   Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
   byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
   Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
   String encryptedString = encoder.encodeToString(encrypted);
   System.out.println(encryptedString);
   ```
2. To decode:

   ```
   Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
   cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
   String decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(decoder.decode(encryptedString)));
   System.out.println(decrypted);
   ```

Comment: thankx Oleg accepted ans. But I am using Java7 so Base64 has issue. For Base64 I found sun.misc anyway this solves the problem.